# AutoIt3 could not send text to Windows browse dialog on virtual machine

Tags: windows, autoit, vmware-workstation

I have a virtual machine (created using VMware, Inc.® VMware vCloud Director) running Windows10 x64 that has AutoIt3 installed.

I run an automated test on this machine that will open a Windows Browse dialog at some point to upload some files to a site.

I use this AutoIt script to handle this dialog:

```
$files = ""
For $i = 1 To UBound($CmdLine) - 1
    $files &= '"' & $CmdLine[$i] & '" '
Next

WinWait("[REGEXPTITLE:(Open|Upload)]")
   Send($files)
   Send("{ENTER}")
```

This is how I run the script on the virtual machine via a java executor:

```
cmd.exe /C start "WATT_AutoIt" AutoIt3.exe C:\autoIT\uploadFiles.au3 "C:\Scanning_autotest_files\file1.pdf"
```

If I open a remote desktop connection window (to the virtual machine) from another machine the AutoIt script works fine and send the text to the browse dialog.

If I minimize the remote desktop the AutoIt script does not send the text.
The same happens for not having any display/remote connection opened to the virtual machine.

Any idea on this?

Comment: Update - I added some logging to the AutoIt script and it seems that it cannot activate the window on the virtual machine if there is any remote desktop connection opened.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out.

If there is no logged in user on the virtual machine then the script is running in Windows Session 0. You cannot activate a window in Session 0 and mouse functions do not work.

So, any ***AutoIt*** function that works with active windows or mouse click will fail in Windows Session 0.

The only solution I found is to work with the window controls directly:
use ***ControlSetText*** to set edit controls and ***ControlSend*** to press button controls.

Here is the final script that worked for me:

```
#include <FileConstants.au3>
#include <AutoItConstants.au3>

writeToFile("-------------------------------------------")

$files = ""
For $i = 1 To UBound($CmdLine) - 1
    $files &= '"' & $CmdLine[$i] & '" '
Next

; wait up to 10s for upload browse window
$handle = WinWait("[REGEXPTITLE:(Open|Upload)]","",10)

If $handle Then
  writeToFile("window found " & $handle)

  ;try to activate the window just to see if it works
  ;it won't work if Windows is in Session 0 (no user writeToFileged in)
  If WinActivate($handle) Then
    writeToFile("window " & $handle & " activated; error: " & @error)
   Else
    writeToFile("window " & $handle & " not activated -> error: " & @error)
  EndIf

  ;set edit control's text even if the window is not Active
  ;if succeeded then click the Open button
  If ControlSetText($handle, "", "[CLASS:Edit; INSTANCE:1]", $files) Then
    writeToFile("Set edit box text succeeded; error: " & @error);

    ;double check previous set text
    $sText = ControlGetText($handle, "", "[CLASS:Edit; INSTANCE:1]")
    writeToFile("Edit box content: " & $sText & "; error: " & @error)
    Sleep(500)
    ;send Enter to the Open button
    ControlSend($handle, "", "[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]", "{ENTER}")
    writeToFile("Send Enter to the Open button; error:" & @error)

   Else
    writeToFile("Set edit box text failed -> error: " & @error);
  EndIf

 Else
  writeToFile("browse window not found after 10s")
EndIf 

Func writeToFile($text)
    Local Const $sFilePath = "C:\test\autoIT\x.out"
    Local $hFileOpen = FileOpen($sFilePath, $FO_READ + $FO_APPEND)
    If $hFileOpen = -1 Then
        MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "An error occurred when reading/writing the file.")
        Return False
    EndIf
    FileWriteLine($hFileOpen, $text)
    FileClose($hFileOpen)
    Return True
EndFunc
```